# Django admin panel showing users from a different django site

Tags: python, django, django-admin, admin

I worked on a django site 2 years ago, and I now started working on another django site. 
But when I go to the admin page of this new site and click on the users category, I see a whole bunch of users that were created from my previous django site?
Why is this happening and how can I reset it so it doesn't show those?

Comment: Default / example users and/or copied DB address+credentials / model over to new project? Perhaps they share the DB (and most likely the "user" table)?

Comment: You probably copied the settings files from the old project and the `DATABASES` settings are the same. If you're running on something else than SQLite (or other one-file databases), it's likely that you're reusing the old database.

Comment: I think the previous one was postgres, and the new one is sqlite.
I don't think I copied any settings. I just gitcloned into a new folder.